# train word2vec with pretrained vectors

Tags: nlp, gensim, word2vec, fasttext

I am training word vectors on particular text corpus using fast text.
Fasttext provides all the necessary mechanics and options for training word vectors and when looked with tsne, the vectors are amazing. I notice gensim has a wrapper for fasttext which is good for accessing vectors.

for my task, I have many text corpuses. I need to use the above trained vectors again with new corpus and use the trained vectors again on new discovered corpuses. fasttext doesnot provide this function. I donot see any package that achieves this or may be I am lost. I see in google [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gensim/Y_WmJST9xx8) gensim provides intersect_word2vec_format, but cannot understand or find usage tutorial for this. There is another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41096821/word2vec-model-intersect-word2vec-format) open similar to this with no answer.

So apart from gensim, is there any other way to train the models like above.

Comment: Hi, were you able to figure it out?

Comment: nope, still have not figured that out, i have to go thru the pain of training all the time.

Comment: you can see gojomo answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46013294/gensim-doc2vec-intersect-word2vec-format-command

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692906/fasttext-using-pre-trained-word-vector-for-text-classification/48967555#48967555

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57033566/10872307) could be helpful for your task.