# How to train a pretrained binary file on my own corpus using gensim?

Tags: nlp, models, gensim, corpus

Hey guys I have a pretrained binary file and I want to train it on my corpus.

**Approach I tried :**

I tried to extract the txt file from the bin file I had and use this as a word2vec file at time of loading and further trained it on my own corpus and saved the model but the model is performing badly for the words which are there in the pre-trained bin file (I used intersect_word2vec_format command for this.)

[Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1AdBYWP1lWrg9QsX4BZ63rpUihyR4BpvS) is the script I used.

What should be my approach for my model to perform well on words from both the pre-trained file and my corpus?

Answer (score 0):

Load your model and use `build_vocab` with `update = True`.

```
import gensim
from gensim.models import Word2Vec

model = Word2Vec.load('w2vmodel.bin')
my_corpus = ... # load your corpus as sentences here
model.build_vocab(my_corpus, update=True)
model.train(my_corpus)
```

It's not really clear to me when `intersect_word2vec_format` is helpful, but you can read more about the intended use case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46013294/gensim-doc2vec-intersect-word2vec-format-command). It does seem it's not for ordinary re-training of vectors though.